# Calculate the next content of a row based on the value of the previous one

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine that a supposed query returns:

```
 ---------- --------- ----------- --------- --------- --------- -------
|   DATE   | USER_ID | USER_NAME | HOURS_A | HOURS_R | RESIDUE | ACCUM |
 ---------- --------- ----------- --------- --------- --------- -------
|2018-03-15| 1234567 |    Joe    |    8    |    8    |    0    |   0   |
|2018-03-17| 1234567 |    Joe    |    8    |    10   |    2    |   2   |
|2018-03-19| 1234567 |    Joe    |    8    |    3    |   -5    |  -3   |
|2018-03-21| 1234567 |    Joe    |    8    |    9    |    1    |  -2   |
 ---------- --------- ----------- --------- --------- --------- -------
```

HOURS_A -> Hours assigned
HOURS_R -> Hours reported
ACCUM   -> Accumulated

As you can see the cell `ACCUM` is getting its value based on the sum of the last value in the `ACCUM` column and the left value of the residue. Can I get this query without using a cursor? Can I accomplish it just by using a simple plain query.

I really have no idea on how to solve it but I don't want you to tell me the literal 'query', instead I am asking for the right way to complete this query. I am currently using PostgreSQL.

I too thought creating a function and using a LOOP but, anyway, I don't have a final decision. What's your best advice to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the aggregate function `sum()` as a window function.

```
with my_table(date, user_id, user_name, hours_a, hours_r, residue) as (
values
    ('2018-03-15', 1234567, 'Joe', 8, 8, 0),
    ('2018-03-17', 1234567, 'Joe', 8, 10, 2),
    ('2018-03-19', 1234567, 'Joe', 8, 3, -5),
    ('2018-03-21', 1234567, 'Joe', 8, 9, 1)
)
select *, sum(residue) over w as accum
from my_table
window w as (partition by user_name order by date)

    date    | user_id | user_name | hours_a | hours_r | residue | accum 
------------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------
 2018-03-15 | 1234567 | Joe       |       8 |       8 |       0 |     0
 2018-03-17 | 1234567 | Joe       |       8 |      10 |       2 |     2
 2018-03-19 | 1234567 | Joe       |       8 |       3 |      -5 |    -3
 2018-03-21 | 1234567 | Joe       |       8 |       9 |       1 |    -2
(4 rows)
```

Read about window functions [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) (pay attention to the last example with salary).

Comment: What about if I have another user_id that must be evaluated in the same way? How do I add a restriction to sum the values per user?

Comment: You should add `partition by user_name` in the widnow declaration, like in the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome klin, thanks for the reference on using window functions, I will read it a lot, and thanks a lot, I will practice it. That was useful.